# Nancy and razor, "Cannot find the type name or namespace .."

Tags: c#, razor, enums, reference, nancy

Since 3 days im trying to repair legacy project in m job (i never done single application in this technologies, sorry for the mistakes made bellow)
After changing Enums place (separate project) we encountered the problem with not compile page views.
After build, and app start we getting "[CS0246] Line: 2 Column: 11 - Cannot find the type name or namespace "Commons" (is the "using" directive or reference to the set missing)?"
But reference is present, nothing changed, sitting here with selected lovely check box. I tried so far almost every single way to adding assemblies and references but nothing changed at all.

I already tried:

- Adding/Removing reference
- Adding/Removing compilated DLL
- Adding all (i think 15+ ways) for assemblies and references.
- File properties
- Commons.Enums namespace
- Changed project
- Changed build targets
- I changed Visual Studio (i don't know why, we using jenkins for production but im loosing sanity from 3 days)
- Added assembly biding
- Compilation tag in config
- Added @using, removed @using
- I tried to compile with/without reference
- Cleaned project manually
- Many, many rebuilds

PS in CS files everthing is fine, only webview is broken

Comment: We cannot really help you. The error is obvious. You are missing the namespace. 
I can only guide you to what might not work. 
1) The project is not referenced that contains the commons namespace.
2) The referenced DLL is not of the same version so it breaks.
These two come in mind. 
3) Napespace collision(unlikely). 

Try explicit specification meaning @using NameOfProject.Core.Helpers.YourClassName where the class is used and not declare the namespace top of the file=> Sth Like this.Does this make sense?

Comment: I asked senior and mid devs from my team. No one know why its broken :/ now im trying to change targets for something like net core.

Comment: I am sorry you are making even less sense now. Visual studio usually provides helpful hints for such issues. Like warnings or Errors. If you want help from this Site you need to refactor your question even provide some screenshots. Please provide what version of .NET you are using. What are you doing in jenkins and what works and what does not work.

Comment: Okey, im using .NET 4.5.2 in ClientPanel and 4.0 in Commons. Everything in VS is correct, no errors (only 4k warnings, but its fine). Evrything compile, when i start application and go to _passes.cshtml. Now i see razor compile error (this from main post) with CS0246.

Comment: We are using Nancy + razor, and issue started afert extraction of enums and helpers from DB project. Problem occurs localy and after jenkins build. I can't provide jenkins build becouse someone in company cut my head out but localy i do only compile with few dependcies.

Comment: Please read this -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . 
Especially the help others reproduce the problem.